# Equations of motion for a system of $n$ particles given the potetial

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, coupled-oscillators, anharmonic-oscillators

I am having difficulties on the following question:

> The equations of motion for a system of n particles are:  $$m \ddot{x}_i = - \dfrac{\partial U(x_1,...,x_n)}{\partial x_i}$$  $$\ddot{x}_i = \dfrac{d^2x_i}{dt^2}$$ where $m$ is mass and $x_i$ is the coordinate of particle i.  $U(x_1,...,x_n)$ is the potential energy of the system.
>   Given $$U(x_1,...,x_n) = \sum^{n-1}_{i=1} \frac{k}{2} (x_{i+1} - x_i)^2 + \sum^{n}_{i,j =1} \frac{\lambda}{4}(x_i - x_j)^4$$
>   Find the equations of motion for particle i using the Kronecker delta.

Could someone please help me with this as I am not even sure how to start this question.

Comment: Just do the partial derivatives and plug them into the first equation.

Comment: But then how do I use the Kronecker delta?

Comment: $\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial x_j} = \delta_{ij}$

Comment: Would someone mind showing me a worked answer to this question, so I know what answer I have to aim for.

Comment: All you need is in the comments and the task. Try to work with this and wrap your head around these concepts, if more specific questions arise, ask them. Do not expect us to do your homework (especially as this can be found in any book on mathematical methods).

Comment: This is not for a homework assignment it is for my own practise for similar questions I will get in the future.  I do my own homework!

Comment: @user2352274 with the word homework, people usually mean homeworky things like exercises etc.

Comment: SO would the partial derivative be equal to $$\frac{\partial}{\partial {x_i}} = k \sum^{n-1}_{i=1} (x_{i+1} - x_i)(\delta _{i, j+1} - \delta_{ij}) +\lambda (\sum^{n}_{i,j =1} (x_i -x_j)^3 (\delta_{ij} - \delta_{ij})$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You apply the chain rule basically, so I'll try help you with the first sum and leave the second for you.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNkzF.jpg
your final comment is correct but the first sum should be over a dummy variable j, and the second should summed over dummy variables j,k.

## FrolovOut

Comment: This site has [MathJax enabled](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation) so that you don't have to copy notes to imgur.

Comment: Now I understand, you use them just like  Levi - Civita tensors. Thanks FrolovOut